# Unable to install SQL Server 2019 on Windows 11

Tags: sql-server

****I would really appreciate if someone can help me to sort this issue, really frustrating.

---

[image: SQL Server 2019 Installation Problem on Windows 11]

Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Feature failure reason:
An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.

> Error details:  Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services
> Instance Features

```
The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.
    Error code: 0x84B40002
    Visithttps://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402 to get help on troubleshooting.
```

Comment: Yes, This is the message when I tried to repair, but the same message was there on first attempt to Install

Comment: The screenshot is of a repair, and it clearly did not install correctly in the first place. You'll need to look in the setup bootstrap folder for the install logs and see where the issue occurred during original installation. Start with the summary.txt and work your way through the detailed logs.